# 'Screenshot' of documents

Tags: c#, image, document, docx

I am looking for ways to convert the first page of a docx (and later excel and powerpoint) document to an image. I would rather not manually parse the document's entire xml since that seems like a lot of work ;)

So I guess I'm just trying to collect some resources on how to best tackle this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in the context of a winforms/wpf or web app / something else?

Comment: Any C# .Net solution will do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering is the most difficult task :-)

I would go something like this:

DOCX -> PDF (via [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx)) -> Render via [Aspose.Pdf.Kit](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/default.aspx)

Not a perfect solutions (in terms of "looks like printed from Word"), but the most suitable I can think of.

In addition, you could use some Microsoft Office interop, which would require Office to be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good thinking (x -> pdf -> img), but using Aspose is a little too costly for a small feature. Will look for alternatives though.

Comment: I found GhostScript that seem to do this extremely well, although it's a 14mb library. I am sitll looking for other alternatives though since this doesn't seem to be very optimized ;)

Comment: Yeah, they request some money from you :-). I'm sure there are other solutions available (maybe sending to Google Docs and do some screen-capturing of the converted DOCX => HTML?!?)

Comment: @Uwe Keim - that sounds illegal for a commerical application.

Comment: How do you know, it is a commercial application? If it would be commercial, he could very well afford the costs of Aspose; it is much cheaper the the labor of the developer trying to build a solution on his one, in my experience.

Comment: It's commercial, but for a feature that's not worth any (or much) expenses.